# I don't know what's wrong with this PHP code

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

So bascially I have a folder in which I have
1) 38-index.php
2) 38-conf.inc.php
3) images(folder)
The purpose of this code is to display nothing but a gif whos path would be derived from another page(conf.inc.php), But it keeps giving me a broken image icon when I run it and nothing else. I checked the frame code and it displays the URL exactly where the gif file is.
BASICALLY I am trying to get a grasp over include and $_SERVER variables and using it to come up with a dynamic page which will modify to the right path regardless of the server it's run from.
PS: I am doing this to learn php during the time of this lockdown.

//CODE FOR 38-index.php

```
<?php

    include '38-conf.inc.php';  

?>

<img src="<?php echo $images.'header.gif'; ?>" />
```

//CODE FOR 38-conf.inc.php

```
<?php

    $host_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $images = $host_name.'/tutorials/38-$_SERVER_hostname/images/';

?>
```

In images folder, I have an image called "header.gif" that's it. Please help! I am really stuck and my OCD won't let me move ahead unless and until I clear this doubt.

As you can see.. when I run my 38-index.php file I want it to open the localhost/tutorials/38-$_SERVER_hostname/images/header.gif file. but all it does is spit correct URL out without any action.

[the frame source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZpCZ.png)

I think I've found the problem here. I right clicked on the URL and opened it up on another tab. It turns out to be the wrong path. THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE FIXED in order to redirect to the .gif file
[incorrect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDFEG.png)

Comment: _"It doesn't seem to work"_ is a _terrible_ description that doesn't give us _anything_ to go on. It also suggests that you're not even sure that there is an issue to begin with. You actually need to tell us what your issue is. We have no idea what you expect that code to do, nor do we know what happens when you run it. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Are you expecting something to be replaced in `'/tutorials/38-$_SERVER_hostname/images/'` (i.e. `$_SERVER`) as single quoted strings do not do substitution.

Comment: Along with @MagnusEriksson's comments, please have something more specific in your title.  At the moment it has no relation to your code other than it doesn't work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry about the vague description I had put up before. Basically I am trying to using the include function to get a dynamic path to the folder containing the gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `http://`, then try this :

```
$images = 'http://'.$host_name.'/tutorials/38-$_SERVER_hostname/images/';
```

Comment: I want my code to generate a dynamic link so that when I run my script, it would come up with the right path to the .gif file that I'm trying to load into my browser
http://localhost/tutorials/38-$_SERVER_hostname/images/header.gif

Comment: @KevinChandarana Yes, did you try one of the three choices ? I think the problem comes from `$_SERVER_hostname`. Can you tell me what is the names of the folders from `/tutorials/` folder to the `/image/` folder in order?

Comment: I replaced and ran all three of your suggestions but it didn't work.
my file path is tutorials > 38-$_SERVER_hostname > images > header.gif

Comment: @KevinChandarana You have a folder named `/38-$_SERVER_hostname/` like this https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/15/30k4.png ?

Comment: Yes, it's a folder